# Java Threads: How to make two threads completely independent

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jvm

Java Threads: How to make two threads completely independent

I have a SWING application in jar format, I am calling the main class of that SWING jar from my JAVA app so that they can use same JVM.

The reason for using the same JVM for Swing application is that I am trying to automate that app and to capture swing components I am calling it in same JVM.

For Running that swing application I am using a separate thread and my main thread contains my automation code.

Everything works fine but after some time application generates a JOption popup which suspends application till an option is selected.

Problem is that this popup pauses/suspends complete application - Swing App+ my app, only one background thread keeps running which is continuously checking for user input

Is there any way to create a Thread which is completely unaffected by other threads??

Comment: AFAIR you can't run two swing thread in one app (at least without magic).

Comment: There is only one Event Dispatch Thread. The threads that run your "app" and the "swing app" may be independent, but mouse and keyboard events all end up in the EDT.

Comment: @talex No I am not running tow Swing thread, only one thread is used for Running Swing another is just normal java code

Comment: Well, where does the JOption come from?

Comment: @RealSkeptic the Swing app displays the JOption Pane, I am using the java code to launch the Swing app using Class loader in a separate thread and interacting with application using JAVA code but when Joption pane is displayed it also hangs my main thread

Comment: And how are you interacting with it?

Comment: there is a library called FEST-Swing, which helps in interacting with Swing Apps if they are loaded in same JVM

Answer (score 0):

I believe that somewhere in your main thread you are directly invoking a Swing component which blocks until it is acknowledged.

You would need to wrap that function which is called from the main thread in it's own Runnable and execute it in a new Thread instance.